# Can I receive Twitter updates without granting write permissions for my Twitter account?

Tags: 11.04, gwibber, notify-osd, twitter

I want to configure a shared computer to display public updates from a specific Twitter account and hashtag. How can I do this without having to grant Gwibber write permissions to my own Twitter account?

What I want to avoid is this:

[image: Gwibber]

[image: Twitter]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no Read Only (via the API) for Gwibber and Twitter. Gwibber uses the OAuth method to associate your twitter account and push/pull data to and from Twitter.

If you page isn't protected you can use your RSS feed and a Desktop [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) Aggregator for Read Only mode.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Twitter doesn't support RSS feeds anymore:

http://support.twitter.com/articles/15361-how-to-find-your-rss-feed

As a workaround, my feeds for searches still work:

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=askubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Gwibber is a full featured twitter client and does not currently have a "read only" mode.

You will need to find another application that has a read only mode (I know of a web app that is read only, but no desktop apps). Or, you can ask gwibber developers to add this feature, or you can fork gwibber and add the feature yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Gwibber to be "read only".

You'll still have to grant Read/Write permissions on Twitters end, however, Gwibber won't let you write anything ("Tweet")

To do that, open up Broadcast preferences, then create a new account (If you haven't already added your Twitter account to Gwibber), and uncheck the "Send Messages" checkbox.

[image]

There you go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question then

Comment: To help clarify, I've posted screenshots of the permissions I do not want to grant.

Comment: What my answer does is it lets you say "Read-Write" according to *Twitter*, but *Gwibber* won't let you do tweet. You'll still need to grant Read/Write, but Gwibber won't ever let you write. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. "You'll still need to grant Read/Write" is explicitly what I asked how to avoid. I am not concerned about *behavior*. I am concerned about *permissions*.